# Callback of location permission popup not get called

Tags: ios, swift4

I have cerated a wrapper class of `CLLocationManager`

```
public class MyLocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  public static let shared = MyLocationManager()

  var locationManager: CLLocationManager

  override init() {
     locationManager = CLLocationManager()
     super.init()
     locationManager.delegate = self
  }

  // function to request location “when-in-use” permission 
  public func requestWhenInUse() {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

  // callback of location permission popup
  private func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        //PROBLEM: it never get called
        print(“Status: \(status)")
    }
}
```

In one of my `UIViewController`, I request location permission by:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    MyLocationManager.shared.requestWhenInUse()
}
```

When run app, location permission popup comes, but after allow or deny permission, the callback inside `MyLocationManager` never get called, why?

I take this as a reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423701-locationmanager

Comment: you need to remove `private` keyword. After removing it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update method to latest syntax

```
public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus){---}
```

Comment: verified init is called ? also do you run it in simulator or device ?

Comment: Yes, verified, init() of MyLocationManager is called.

Comment: Not working still. I have changed to the latest syntax. Also updated my code above with latest syntax.

Comment: I think. No need to add private/public keywords for delegate methods.

Comment: @Natarajan I tested it with no access modifier and  with private ,, only it works with public that removed the warning